# Black spider identification

Tags: species-identification, zoology, arachnology

Location is in Canada / Ottawa

I did a web search, but I can't figure out what species it is.

[image: spider]

Comment: If it is still there could you take pictures showing its eyes?

Comment: plz mention some measurement; approximate at least

Answer (score 3):

This is very likely an araneid (or **Orb-weaver spider**) in the family [Araneidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orb-weaver_spider).

Without further evidence/details, it's hard to narrow down to a species.

One possibility is [***Larinioides sclopetarius***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larinioides_sclopetarius) (the **bridge spider** or **gray cross spider**).

[image] [image]

<sup>Source: [Ed Nieuwenhuys](https://ednieuw.home.xs4all.nl/Spiders/Araneidae/Araneidae.htm)</sup>

[image] [image]

<sup>Source: [Eurospiders.com](http://www.eurospiders.com/Larinioides_sclopetarius.htm)</sup>

- *Description*:

  > Prosoma grey to grey-brown. Opisthosoma grey to grey-brown, dorsally with pronounced, white margined pattern. [Source: [University of Bern](http://www.araneae.unibe.ch/data/1204/Larinioides_sclopetarius)]

  - See [University of Bern](http://www.araneae.unibe.ch/data/1204/Larinioides_sclopetarius) for detailed drawings of anatomical structures.
- *Size*: females = 10-14 mm ; males = 8-9 mm.
- *Web*: orb webs can have diameters of up to 70 cm.
- *Ecology*: often lives on briges or near water; often found on steel structures.
- *Range*: [holoarctic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holarctic) including Ottawa, Canada

  [image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e8/Distribution.larinioides.sclopetarius.1.png]

---

**What it's NOT**

Although visually similar, this is *not* 
[***Nuctenea umbratica***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuctenea_umbratica) (**walnut orb-weaver**)

[image: http://www.rspb.org.uk/community/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/15765/Araneidae-Nuctenea-umbratica_2C00_-Walnut-Orb_2D00_weaver-Spider_2C00_-Saint-Sorlin-de-Conac_2D00_1a_2C00_-06032015-HW.JPG]

<sup>[Source](http://media.photobucket.com/user/Simeczka/media/DSC_0109.jpg.html?filters[term]=Larinioides%20ixobolus%20female&filters[primary]=images&filters[secondary]=videos&sort=1&o=8)</sup>

- This species is confined to [Europe, Asia and Africa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuctenea_umbratica#/media/File:Distribution.nuctenea.umbratica.1.png).

The specimen is also unlikely [***Larinioides ixobolus***](http://www.araneae.unibe.ch/data/635/Larinioides_ixobolus), which generally has a black outline (vs white) on their backs And is constrained to Europe/Asia:

[image]

<sup>[Source](http://www.rspb.org.uk/community/wildlife/f/15765/t/114141.aspx?pi2132219858=2)</sup>

Comment: you posted a similar answer in a different question

Answer (score 1):

Possibly incorrect, but it looks like some kind of orb weaver - from the shape of the abdomen and the posture, it's very similar to a lot of orb weavers and potentially is in the *Araneus* genus.

I don't think it's this species, but you can perhaps see the similarities;
http://www.spiders.us/species/araneus-diadematus/#more_pictures

It could also be an immature, hard to know :/